# rxjs tree search

Tags: tree, rxjs

I'm new to rxjs and need to find an algorithm to find nodes by id inside a tree. That's my best approach (available as public gist in [gistrun](https://gist.run/?id=c1df845f54f90cfa209c517c5fb173e1)) :

```
const value= "c.1.3";
const tree= [
  {
    "id": "c.1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "c.1.1"
      },
      {
        "id": "c.1.2"
      },
      {
        "id": "c.1.3"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const findTree= (tree)=>Rx.Observable.from(tree)
  .mergeMap(node=>{
    if(!!node.children)
      return findTree(node.children);
    return Rx.Observable.of(node);
  })
  .find(node=>node.id==value);
findTree(tree).subscribe(console.info);
```

It's failing finding the root, I would like to walk only throw the leafs matching the id start and discard that I'm inventing the wheel.

1. **How can I maintain the search at first level?**
2. **Is there any operator to filter by regexp?**
3. **Any rxjs operator does a recursive find?**

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: My first question would be, why do you want to make this code observable?

Comment: There is no special need, as new to the reactive approach I'm trying to implement everything as streams. I wonder if I could manage with the benefits of functional (inmmutabilty, side effect free and declaratibity) plus reactive (elacticity) my tree model, related to a tagging system which will grow infinitely in time. I've many workarounds to this solution, but I'm really curious about this...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I won't get into detail with your tree example, but I can answer your questions and this may help you figure out some things.

**How can I maintain state**

One easy way to do that, is to save your state in a temporary object

```
Observable.of(1)
          .flatMap(number => Observable.of({ start: number, value: 'a' }))
          .subscribe(({start, value}) => console.log(start + '/' + value)); // output: 1/a
```

**Is there any operator to filter by regexp?**

No, but you can easily do it yourself like that

```
let names$ = Observable.of('adam', 'amy', 'ben');
let regex = /a.*/;

names$.filter(name => regex.test(name))  // emits: 'adam', 'amy
```

**Any rxjs operator does a recursive find?**

Yes, there is the expand operator. Here is an easy example which should guide you the way

```
Observable.of(3)
          .expand(x => Observable.of(x-1))
          .takeWhile(x => x >= 0); // emits: 3, 2, 1, 0
```